# How to remove dataset line inside sklearn Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using a custom transformer inside sklearn pipeline. The transformer removes lines from data set, but it seems it can only remove the lines from X, but not from y.
I see the pipeline automatically calls fit_transform method of the transformer. Current implementation of sklearn 1.2 TransformerMixin method fit_transform calls fit(X, y) and then transform(X)
Pipeline object in method transform also returns only X, not y.
It seems to me a Transformer cannot really modify y.

What is the correct way to remove a line from both X and y sets inside Pipeline if not by Transformer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lines"? It would be more helpful if you could give more details about your issue and the problem statement

Comment: @spectre remove observations from the dataset, or remove rows from the main dataframe from which both X and y are derived

Answer (score 2):

(By 'removing lines', I assume you mean 'filter out samples')

In general, `sklearn`'s transformers focus more on the features. For your case, there are 2 solutions:

1. Filter out the samples before/after the pipeline if possible. This is an easier approach.
2. Overwrite part of the custom transformer API. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896178/sklearn-have-an-estimator-that-filters-samples) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn does not support removing rows in a pipeline. One option is to use the [imbalanced-learn](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/) 
package which is scikit-learn compatible and supports removing rows in a pipeline.

Here is an example:

```py
from imblearn          import FunctionSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.tree      import DecisionTreeClassifier


def filter_data(X, y):
    "Remove data from both X and y."
    return X[:-1], y[:-1] # Hard code dropping last row

pipe = Pipeline([('filter', FunctionSampler(func=filter_data)),
                 ('clf',    DecisionTreeClassifier()),])
pipe.fit(X, y)
```